# No software manager on Ubuntu GNOME Remix fix?

Tags: gnome

I have just installed Ubuntu GNOME Remix 12.10.1 and I when I first booted I ran the software manager and then went to the software updater to install updates. After the reboot, I can no longer find the software manager. I can see the updater when I search software but no manager. How can I get it back?

Comment: I don't think you can make this question here, because Ubuntu GNOME Remix, is not a "real Ubuntu", at the project site you can read the following message in the bottom: "This project is not affiliated with, authorized by, sponsored by, or otherwise approved by Canonical and/or the GNOME Foundation."

Comment: The question may be valid, hard to say. It's still Ubuntu underneath it all. I think not allowing the custom "remix" may be a lot like  not allowing s3 questions, or questions that belong to people that have `apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @coteyr note that the project is not approved by Canonical and/or the GNOME Foundation, it means that it might have bugs.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/ReleaseNotes/12.10 Seems to imply that the Gnome Remix is "The Ubuntu GNOME Remix is a mostly pure GNOME desktop experience built from the Ubuntu repositories."

Comment: Let just flag and the mods earn their Rep :)

Comment: UGR questions is discussed on Meta (http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5402/are-software-issues-about-ubuntu-gnome-remix-on-topic-or-off-topic) - currently the community regards these as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you first time run the system update, the software manager uninstalls.

To fix this run

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-packagekit
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get a gnome compatable update manager running again by installing update-manager

`sudo apt-get install update-manager`